# Split Character Strings with different combinations based on letter in R

Tags: r, character, strsplit

I have a large data frame with a character column containing a different combination of strings.

For example

```
**Column1**
1.0.01.01 
1.02.04.03 | E1.3  
G1.2 | 5.01.03.2
30.02.01.04.02 
I.1
10.04.03 | H1.256
```

The only values I am interested in are the ones starting with a letter. My desired output should look like this:

```
**Column1**
NA
E1.3  
G1.2
NA
I.1
H1.256
```

Testdata:

```
structure(list(Column1 = c("1.0.01.01", "1.02.04.03 | E1.3",
"G1.2 | 5.01.03.2", "30.02.01.04.02", "I.1", "10.04.03 | H1.256")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I guess the solution might be really simple with grepl or similar commands, but at the moment I am missing the right idea for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach, assuming df is your data frame and Column1 is your column name.

```
stringr::str_extract(df$Column1, '[a-zA-Z]+\\d*\\.\\d+')
```

[a-zA-Z] search for one or more alphabets followed by zero or more matches of digits, followed by dot and then followed by digits

**Output**:

```
[1] NA       "E1.3"   "G1.2"   NA       "I.1"    "H1.256"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `^[[:alpha:]]` to find with `grep` if it starts with a character.

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x$Column1, " \\| "), function(x)
   grep("^[[:alpha:]]", x, value = TRUE)[1]))
#[1] NA       "E1.3"   "G1.2"   NA       "I.1"    "H1.256"
```

In case there are no surrounding spaces:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x$Column1, "\\|"), function(x) 
   grep("^[[:alpha:]]", trimws(x), value = TRUE)[1]))
```

And in case there is more than one match per line (with `""` instead of `NA`):

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x$Column1, " \\| "), function(x)
  paste(grep("^[[:alpha:]]", x, value = TRUE), collapse = " | ")))
```

or using `sub`:

```
sub("^.*\\b([[:alpha:]][^ ]+).*$|.*", "\\1", x$Column1)
```

Or using `regexec` and `regmatches`

```
tt <- regmatches(x$Column1, regexec("\\b[[:alpha:]][^ ]*", x$Column1))
tt[lengths(tt)==0] <- NA;
unlist(tt)
```

Comment: It works on the sample data, but what if some values have a "|" without surrounding spaces? I liked your version with the trimws(x). Wondering when that nice function was added to R. I always had to look it up in the help page of grep!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I tried. Your data is called `mydf`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

mutate(mydf,
       newcol = unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(str = Column1,
                                              pattern = "(?<=\\s|^)[A-Z].*?(?=\\s|$)")))

            Column1 newcol
1         1.0.01.01   <NA>
2 1.02.04.03 | E1.3   E1.3
3  G1.2 | 5.01.03.2   G1.2
4    30.02.01.04.02   <NA>
5               I.1    I.1
6 10.04.03 | H1.256 H1.256
```

Another way that I had was the following.

```
mutate(mydf, group = 1:n()) %>% 
separate_rows(Column1, sep = "\\s\\|\\s") %>% 
filter(grepl(x = Column1, pattern = "^[A-Z]")) %>% 
complete(group = 1:nrow(mydf))

  group Column1
  <int> <chr>  
1     1 NA     
2     2 E1.3   
3     3 G1.2   
4     4 NA     
5     5 I.1    
6     6 H1.256
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution using `regmatches`

```
df <- within(df, 
             Column2 <- unlist(replace(u<<-regmatches(Column1,
                                                      gregexpr("\\b[[:alpha:]][\\.\\d]+\\b",
                                                               Column1,perl = TRUE)),
                                       !lengths(u),
                                       NA)))
```

such that

```
> df
            Column1 Column2
1         1.0.01.01    <NA>
2 1.02.04.03 | E1.3    E1.3
3  G1.2 | 5.01.03.2    G1.2
4    30.02.01.04.02    <NA>
5               I.1     I.1
6 10.04.03 | H1.256  H1.256
```